# C# errror "CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get an error, `Assets\scripts\Skins.cs(9,12): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods` on the Internet they write what it means incorrectly placed brackets, but I don’t see any errors

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public GameObject choise1;
public GameObject choise2;
public GameObject choise3;

public int skin = 1;

public class Skins : MonoBehaviour {

    void Choise () {
        if (Input.GetMouseDown(choise1)){
            choise2.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the line `public class Skins ...`  up, after the last `using`. All the game objects should be part of your class.

Comment: You should probably move the declaration of your three `choiseX` variables and `skin` inside the `Skins` class.

Comment: Off topic: depending on how many choices you have, you might consider using an array instead of lots of individually named and numbered variables.

Comment: And also consider adding a `namespace XXX` declaration; it's unusual to write classes without any namespace declaration at all

Comment: Have you tried [searching this error](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22C%23+error+%22CS0116%3A+A+namespace+cannot+directly+contain+members+such+as+fields+or+methods%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) before posting your question ... ? The message is quite self-explanatory

Comment: What is `if (Input.GetMouseDown(choise1))` trying to do?

Comment: You should not edit your question completely after you have found the answer to it ... The code you show now does not produce the original error anymore!

Comment: @derHugo I have rolled back the changes to show the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GameObject and that int skin need to be under Skins class, like  Choise

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Skins : MonoBehaviour {

        
    public GameObject choise1;
    public GameObject choise2;
    public GameObject choise3;

    public int skin = 1;
    void Choise () {
        if (Input.GetMouseDown(choise1)){
            choise2.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}
```

If you still have some problems here, because I don't know what are u trying to do with that choiseX, maybe you need to create them.
I mean, maybe u are trying to write something like this

```
void Choise () {
        var GameObject choise1 = new GameObject();
        var GameObject choise2 = new GameObject();
        var GameObject choise3 = new GameObject();

        int skin = 1;
        if (Input.GetMouseDown(choise1)){
            choise2.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be a comment. Please include amended code to be considered an answer.

Comment: i put the objects in the class but it still doesn't work. using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Skins : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject choise1;
    public GameObject choise2;
    public GameObject choise3;

    public int skin = 1;

    void Choise () {
        if (Input.GetMouseDown(choise1)){
            choise2.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}

Comment: @phuzi Yes, I know that but I need 50 Reputation for comment on the question, I only can write an answer that's my way of how can I help someone. In the future, that will be a comment. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Ilya Did you find a solution for that? Or you still need some help? If you need something just write an error or something more.

Comment: There is a reason for that, perhaps you should wait to comment until you have enough reputation.

Comment: @phuzi I understand you, but I just wanna help someone. So that's my point here. Have a good day sir!

Comment: You would only need to update your answer to include the corrected code giving an explanation of why to become a "proper" answer.

Comment: @Ilya I'm betting you get a different error though.

Comment: `new GameObject` is **not** what you want to use here! In Unity the `public` (and `[Serializefield] private`) fields are **exposed** in the Inspector and the `GameObject`s to be referenced there .. you don't want to create 3 new ones ;) ... `choice1` is still a `GameObject` and no valid argument for [`Input.GetMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) which expects an `int` for the according button index ...